# mysql cluster auto increment out of sync

Tags: mysql, synchronization, auto-increment, cluster-computing

I have two mysql cluster data nodes as Master and slave. But after certain number of rows there is difference between two auto_increment values from one node to another.
The difference is of Node 2 is ahead than node 1 by 11.

can anyone suggest any fix on this? how to resolve this. and when such type of situation comes?

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Manasi

Comment: are you using nbd clustering, or master/slave replication?

Answer (score 6):

I got the answer for this. Would like to share it on Stackoverflow as noone answered it here.

There is always a difference between two nodes as every node reserve some auto incremented Id's, so the other node will not use it and there will not be any confilcts or mismatch.

Hope this will help someone.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: When you have a server arrangement with more than one DB server having write permissions to the data (either NDB or multiple master replication for example), avoiding auto-increments and using another value for PK storage, a timestamp, a checksum etc works out better in the long run.

Comment: Can we connect on this to discuss in details?